# How to call the "full page screenshot" function in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I am writing a chrome extension and need to screenshot the full page using javascript. I find that chrome has already offered powerful screenshot function in its development tool:

Just open the develop tool, use command+shift+p to run "capture full size screenshot" command.(my reputation is not enough for posting images here, sorry for that)

How to call this function from extension code?

Comment: It can be accessed via chrome.debugger API, specifically [Page.captureScreenshot](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot). However it's limited to 16384px height so you might want to invoke chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab in a loop while automatically scrolling the page, then stitch the results via canvas. Look for examples yourself.

Comment: I tried Page.captureScreenshot, it's really useful. However, I haven't find a derivatively way to screenshot for the full page. I can only get the base64 data of a single screen in view. Has it provided the full page screenshot option or I have to Splice every view into a whole page by myself?